# catch ajax response depending upon the attributes returned from the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, spring-mvc

> I have a ajax function as follows:

```
$.ajax({// defining the below function as ajax responsive//
    url:'Type&State', // the function that process the  mapped url name and matching type is going to receive the data//
    type:'POST',
    data:{state_name:name,case_type:type},// function to get the value from jsp page and send it to mapped class function//
    success: function(response){// if the backend process is success then the function will run by getting the response as its parameter//
            alert(response.message);
            load();
    },
    error: function(response){
          alert("unable to pull up any electricians or plumbers for the selected state");
                        }   
});
```

}

```
load = function(){  
    $.ajax({
        url:'list',
        type:'POST',
        success: function(response){
                data = response.data;
                $('.tr').remove();
                for(i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){                  
                    $("#table").append("<tr class='tr'> <td> "+response.data[i].user_name+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].user_email);
                }           
        }               
    });
```

> Now depending upon the user input my controller may retun user data or
>   admin data,i know how to capture user data (email and name) but it may
>   not return user data type,so could any one please tell me how to configure success or load function to
>   print the response of admin data when the response contains admin attributes and how to print user data when the response contains user attributes, Thank you!

Comment: No way for us to know without seeing the differences. Post a minimal representation showing the difference between the two types.

Comment: And how specifically do you decide which type to send?

Comment: @charlietfl i have a controller which process user data on if and else statements if returns user attributes and else returns admin attributes

Comment: @charlietfl its decided based upon a radio button value which will take as an input from user and process that value in my dao which is autowired to my controller

Comment: Ok so if that radio was selected you know what type of data you get back. So not really clear what specific problem is

Comment: @charlietfl how is that relevant its working fine i cant post my entire project here no one will have the time to go through it brother

Comment: @charlietfl simple if client seeks user attributes controller will execute if or if client seeks admin attributes else part will execute and returns the admin attributes

Comment: Ok so what I understand is if radio for admin is selected...admin data comes back, otherwise is user data. After that you say you have issue rendering but haven;t been specific about exactly what that problem is. Can check if the radio is checked to know which to render. Then it's a matter of what to render. have no idea what the differences are

Comment: @charlietfl the client data is processed by the controller and it either sends admin data attributes or user data attributes right? now under sucess function of ajax if i write code to print the response of both user and admin it will throw exception as only one type(user or admin ) has been sent as response by the controller

Comment: So can't you get status of radio and decide what to render based on that?

Comment: "its decided based upon a radio button value which will take as an input from user". Since **you** can get which radio button was checked, **you** know what the controller knows (what type of data is being sent back), so **you** can process the incoming data based on what **you** know. What's so hard to understand about that?